# Can't modify XLSX exists on google drive

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets-api, xlsx, gspread

I uploaded .xlsx successfully from my local PC to google drive using this simple function.
The mimetype I am using should convert .xlsx to normal google sheet

```
def writeToGDrive(filename):
    file_metadata = {'name': filename,'parents': [FOLDER_ID]}
    media = MediaFileUpload(filename,mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
    officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', resumable=True)
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,media_body=media,fields='id').execute()
    return file.get('id')
```

but when I am trying to read or edit

```
mySpread=service_sheet.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadSheet_Id).execute()
```

It gives me this error

> returned "This operation is not supported for this document">

Also when tried to use gspread it gives me this error

> gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'This operation is not supported for this document', 'status': 'FAILED_PRECONDITION'}

I want to edit this .xlsx on google drive then export it as .xlsx again to local drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to upload a XLSX file by converting as Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.

#### Modification point:

- In this case, how about including the mimeType of the Google Spreadsheet in the file metadata?

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows and test it again.

From:

```
file_metadata = {'name': filename,'parents': [FOLDER_ID]}
```

To:

```
file_metadata = {'name': filename, 'parents': [FOLDER_ID], 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'}
```

- By above modification, the returned file ID can be used as the Google Spreadsheet.

#### Note:

- When you exported it as XLSX file, please use the method of "Files: export" as follows.

  ```
    request = service.files().export_media(fileId=fileId, mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    fh = io.FileIO('exportedSample.xlsx', mode='wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print('Download %d%%.' % int(status.progress() * 100))
  ```

#### References:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)

Comment: @Hanna Nabil Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.